# How to use handle_click on chart to filter values?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use a ggvis barchart to filter values in shiny (as if it was a checkbox input). I am able to select as many checkboxes I want by clicking on any of the bars in the chart, but I cannot deselect them by clicking on the same bar again.

I tried writing an `if` statement (commented) but the checkbox keeps flickering, since `barValue()` enters and infinite loop. I suspect the issue is due to the reactivity of `tblCar()`, but I am not sure how to move further...maybe I should put `tblCar` within an observe?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)


a <- row.names(mtcars)
names(a) <- row.names(mtcars)
as.list(a)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(



      checkboxGroupInput("carModel", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                         choices = as.list(a),
                         selected = 1)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      ggvisOutput('countBar'),
      tableOutput('tblCar')
    )
  )
))
```

The `if` statement for deselecting is commented out.

**server.R**

```
    library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  barValue <- function(data, location, session, ...) {
    data$stack_lwr_ <- NULL
   # if (data$x_ %in% input$carModel) {
   #    return( updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,'carModel',selected = input$carModel[! input$carModel %in% data$x_ ]) )
   #   } else {
    print(paste(data$x_))
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,'carModel',selected = c(data$x_,input$carModel))
   #}

  }

  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$checkGroup })

  #barchart-menu
  tbl_df(mtcars) %>% mutate(cars=row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
    ggvis(~cars, ~mpg) %>% layer_bars()  %>% 
    handle_click(barValue) %>% 
    bind_shiny('countBar', 'ui_countBar')


  tblCar <- reactive({
    req(input$carModel)
      tbl_df(mtcars) %>% mutate(cars=row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
          filter(cars %in% input$carModel)
  })


  output$tblCar <- renderTable({
           tblCar()      
              })

})
```

**global.R**

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)
```

Comment: The other issue:  you should replace `==` with `%in%` operator: `filter(cars %in% input$carModel)`. `==` doesn't work with multiple comparisons. In reactive `tblCar` you should also put `req(input$carModel)` and remove `if statement` from `renderTable`.

Comment: @UnnamedUser thanks I have edited accordingly